# codeigniter how to show data in functions

Tags: codeigniter, get, show

My model:

```
function get_data($id)
{   
    $this->db->select('id, Company, JobTitle');     
    $this->db->from('client_list');     
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();              

    return $query->result();
}
```

I want to get the the data from `get_data()`, is this the right way?

```
public function show_data( $id )
{
    $data = $this->get_data($id);
    echo    '<tr>';     
    echo    '<td>'.$data['Company'].'</td>';                            
    echo    '<td>'.$data['JobTitle'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$data['id'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td></td>';        
    echo    '</tr>';                                        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `row_array()` function to get the data in the array format.

Reference url

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach loop to print

```
foreach ($data->result() as $row)
{
    echo    '<tr>';     
    echo    '<td>'.$row['Company'].'</td>';                            
    echo    '<td>'.$row['JobTitle'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td></td>';        
    echo    '</tr>'; 
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

just to improve answer, I use `"general_model"` for all my controllers, there are some exceptions where I need special queries, I just create desired model so "general_model" stays same and I can use it in any project.

e.g.

**general_model.php**

```
function _getWhere($table = 'table', $select = 'id, name', $where = array()) {

    $this->db->select($select);
    $q = $this->db->get_where('`'.$table.'`', $where);

    return ($q->num_rows() > 0) ? $q->result() : FALSE;
}
.
.
.
//bunch of another functions
```

in **controller** I just call

```
$this->data['books'] = $this->general_model->_getWhere('book', '*', array('active' => '1'));
$this->render('book_list_view'); // $this->load->view('book_list_view', $this->data);
```

*sidenote*: I am extending CI_Controller therefore I use `$this->data['books']` instead `$data['books']` to pass data into view

in **view**

```
//check if there are any data
if ($books === FALSE) {
    //some error that there are no books yet
} else {
    //load data to table or something
    foreach ($books as $book) {
        $book->id; // book id
    }
}
```